# Validar campo de datatimepick con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo ese código:

```
$(function () {
  $('#from').datetimepicker({
    /* language: 'es',*/
    sideBySide: true,
    minDate: new Date()
  });

  $('#to').datetimepicker({
    /*   language: 'es',*/
    sideBySide: true,
    minDate: new Date()
  });
});
```

Me gustaría poner adentro de la misma función una validación que el "from" no puede ser mayor que el "to". ¿Se puede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, en realidad si se puede. Lo que yo haría seria agregar un evento de cambio al "to" para que cuando cambie verifique si la fecha es mayor a la ingresada en el "from". Un ejemplo de como quedaría seria así:

```
$(function () {
  $('#from').datetimepicker({
    /* language: 'es',*/
    sideBySide: true,
    minDate: new Date()
  });

  $('#to').datetimepicker({
    /*   language: 'es',*/
    sideBySide: true,
    minDate: new Date()
  });

  // Entonces aquí agregamos el evento de cambio

  $('#from').on('change', function() {
    // Obtenemos los valores de #from y #to
    var from = $(this).val();
    var to = $('#to').val();

    /* Si el valor de #from es mayor que el valor de #to, 
    mostramos un mensaje de error o ejecutamos alguna función que queramos*/

    if (from > to) {
      alert('El valor de "Desde" no puede ser mayor que el valor de "Hasta"');
    }
  });
});
```

Ya en la función puedes hacer los cambios que necesites como por ejemplo deshabilitar el input, reiniciarlo o colocarlo en una fecha que sea menor al "to"

Otra solución que puede resultar conveniente es usar lo que la documentación sugiere para el manejo de eventos. Por ejemplo para manejar el evento del cambio dentro de las funciones principales podría ser de la siguiente forma:

```
jQuery('#datapicker').datetimepicker({
  timepicker:false,
  onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
    alert($input.val())
  }
});
```

Aunque sugiero la primera solución ya que la puedes aplicar a otros componentes de tu proyecto si así lo quisieras y de esa forma reciclarías código.

Espero y te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciono!!!!!